# Managing associative arrays using different variables

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to use associative arrays in a php script.
I've found that,even by using the same value as key, if the variable isn't exactly the same the array indexing doesn't work. I mean:

```
$index=3;
$array['$index']='first';
echo $array['$index'];
first

$secondIndex=3;
echo $array['$secondIndex'];
```

And this echo gives no output. I'd need to know about this because I'm using as first index a variable that becomes no more retrievable once I'm echoing the second time. Could someone confirm if is this a real problem or just a particular case, and provide some kind of solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$array['$index']` and `$array['$secondIndex']` use different keys. What you want is `$array[$index]` and `$array[$secondIndex]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable name inside single quote is treat as string. So

'$index' will be treated as string '$index' and '$secondIndex' as string `$secondIndex`. That is why you get no output on second echo, because key `$secondIndex` is not set.

To fix it, change it to:

```
<?php
   $index=3;
   $array[$index]='first';
   echo $array[$index];
```

will print text 'first' same as output of following code:

```
<?php
   $secondIndex=3;
   echo $array[$secondIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `var_dump()` and you'll get to know what is happening actually:

```
$index=3;
$array['$index']='first';
echo $array['$index'];
var_dump($array);
```

It will basically print following output from which you can confirm what exactly there in the index.

```
firstarray(1) {
  ["$index"]=>
  string(5) "first"
}
```

So, the index is not `3` as you would have guessed but string `$index`.

Comment: Feeling so dumb by forgetting the sacred var_dump function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can always upvote the answer if you find it useful. :)